# How can I create a folder using a rectangle in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, rectangles

I'm currently working on an app and I want to create some kind of folders for it, I don't want to work with an image, so I want to do it with rectangles, but I'm afraid I'm not that clever, so I'm asking here if you can help me with this.

Many thanks in advance.

[image: What I want]

This is my current code:

```
ZStack{
            
            VStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                    .fill(Color("marineblau"))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 80)
            }
            
            VStack{
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                    .fill(Color("blau"))
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 110)
            }
        }
```

Comment: "I don't want to work with an image." Why not? There are a few SF Symbols that you can use for this.

Comment: @Sweeper Because, firstly, it becomes blurred, and secondly, it doesn't fit my app.

Comment: SF Symbols are vector images, so they won't "become blurred" (if "becomes blurred" refers to what happens when you resize a bitmap image). If "it doesn't fit your app", you need to be very specific about what kind of "folder" graphic you are trying to create. Please describe it precisely.

Comment: @Sweeper I would like to be a little more variable with the design, i.e. size but also colour, with a vector graphic I would have to create a new design every time for a new colour.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can make your own Symbols to achieve that. Anyway, you need to describe precisely what you want to draw, not just "a folder".

Comment: @Sweeper Unfortunately, I can't get the form I need for the folder (and I only need the folder for this specific one in the app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this ?

```
    ZStack{

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .fill(.black) // Change the color
                .frame(width: 60, height: 80)
                .offset(x: -45, y: -30)

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(.black) // Change the color
                .frame(width: 150, height: 80)
                .offset(y: -25)


            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(.blue)  // Change the color
                .frame(width: 150, height: 110)

        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "chart.bar.xaxis.ascending")
            Text("Name")

        }
        .font(.title3.bold())
        .foregroundStyle(.white)

    }
```

[image]

or like this :

```
    ZStack{

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                .fill(.black) // Change the color
                .frame(width: 60, height: 80)
                .offset(x: -45, y: -32)
                .overlay(
                    Path { path in
                        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 50))
                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
                        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
                        path.closeSubpath()
                    }
                        .fill(Color.black)
                        .offset(x: 12, y: -32)
                )

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(.black) // Change the color
                .frame(width: 150, height: 80)
                .offset(y: -25)

            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(.blue)  // Change the color
                .frame(width: 150, height: 110)

        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "chart.bar.xaxis.ascending")
            Text("Name")

        }
        .font(.title3.bold())
        .foregroundStyle(.white)

    }
```

[image]

Comment: The first 3 `VStack` (containing the rounded rectangles) are completely redundant and can be omitted. Also, suggest using padding instead of offsets, otherwise the rectangles will overflow the frame of the `ZStack`.

Comment: @BenzyNeez Indeed the first 3 vstacks are useless. I just deleted them